# socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMP) on NDK

Tags: android, c, sockets, android-ndk, icmp

NDK programing for Android in C language: I need to create a ICMP socket with the following code:

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMP)
```

It fails. Does somebody know why?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer by myself:

```
echo 0 65535 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ping_group_range
```

Modify the config , the ICMP socket will create successed!